Power BI Table Variable not responding to filter
I am trying to create a column that adds a 1 to the first unqiue value in a column and a 0 in the follwing duplicates. I have acheived this by creating the following columns.

RAND = [PROPOSITION_CD] + RAND()

flag = 
VAR __PRPSTN_DS_CurrRow = [PRPSTN_DS]
VAR __PROPOSITION_CD_CurrRow = [PROPOSITION_CD]
VAR __tbl =
    FILTER (
        'sheet2',
        'Sheet2'[PRPSTN_DS] = __PRPSTN_DS_CurrRow
            && 'Sheet2'[PROPOSITION_CD] = __PROPOSITION_CD_CurrRow
    )
VAR __tbl2 =
    TOPN ( 1, __tbl, [RAND], ASC )
VAR __rnd =
    SUMX ( __tbl2, [RAND] )
    
RETURN
    IF ( __rnd = [RAND], 1, 0 )

The issue I have is that when I filter table 2 using a slicer that filter is not reflected in the flag column.
I tried the code above and get the following result which is correct. what i want to happen is when I filter INT0T, INT0W falg value should update to 1


You can't make DAX columns dynamic? If that is what you trying to say??

Can you provide some input data and the expected output ?
